In amCharts 5 how to access grouped data on XY chart with Date Axis?
I have amChart5 XY Chart with value axis, date axis and grouping by date axis enabled.
When data grouping kicks in I need to get calculated(grouped) value for certain date. How can I accomplish this?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found out that lineSeries have dataItems which represents the grouped data so that would be the solution.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
